# Ubuntu 12.04 wallpaper problem when using two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-background

I am using two monitors. The main resolution is 1920x1080 and the secondary is 1440x900. Everything seems to work fine (with default drivers - fglrx crashes badly), besides windows opening in the wrong monitor (even when the main is set correctly), but now what I am trying to fix is the wallpaper problem.

[image: the problem with the wallpaper]

<sup>Click on the image to see a full resolution version</sup>

It also happens with gradients. The secondary monitor is physically aligned like in the image, lower than the other, the wallpaper on the main screen seems to keep the size of the lower resolution, and then it starts at the correct resolution the last part at right.

Is there any way to fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome-Shell 3.4.1. The VGA is a Radeon HD 6950.

---

**UPDATE**

I went to gnome-tweak-tool and disabled *Have file manager handle the desktop*, and now it looks ok on both monitors, but I can't have icons on my desktop, so I am still interested in solving it.

**UPDATE2**

Disabling *Have file manager handle the desktop*, in gnome-tweak-tool and then re-enabling it seems to work, but has to be done every time you turn on the PC.

Comment: I have a similar issue while using three monitors. I've got a large wallpaper (7680x1600), and when I set it to "span", screens #1 and #2 get the first third of the wallpaper, and screen #3 gets the middle third.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/181368/notebook-dual-monitor-setup-wallpaper-resolution-changes-on-restart-or-relog/189415#189415  workaround for the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve the problem is to install nitrogen.

Nitrogen will set a background on each monitor.

You would then run `nitrogen --restore` as a custom command at login.

[image: Nitrogen]

Comment: Do you know if with nitrogen I can use that blue strips wallpaper that "changes throughout the day"?

Comment: Not sure, give it a try and let us know.

Comment: Nitrogen only seems to be able to change the wallpaper on my leftmost screen (of 3 screens). It only changes the wallpaper when the dropdown has "Full Screen" or "Screen 2" selected. "Screen 1" and "Screen 3" do nothing.

Comment: @Eric Lathrop ouch, I've not seen that behavior before, I suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `nitrogen --restore` isn't working for me, any ideas how to troubleshoot this? Everything else works, I've disabled desktop icons and can run nitrogen and set the background no problem. I just can't get it working automatically at login. I have /home encrypted but shouldn't be an issue as it's mounted at login anyway.

Comment: run the command from a terminal, see if it works or you get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following two entries in your .xprofile file. At a terminal type:

```
gedit $HOME/.xprofile
```

and add the following lines:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

and then make the file executable

```
chmod +x $HOME/.xprofile
```

This will disable and enable this setting every time you login.