# Notebook Dual Monitor Setup - wallpaper resolution changes on restart or relog

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, laptop, resolution, desktop-background

On every relog or restart the wallpaper resolution on my external monitor is downgraded to the resolution of my smaller notebook panel. As a result, crisp and clear backgrounds, such as the ones Precise comes with, are rendered blurry. To revert the changes made by the system each time I have to reset the wallpaper with this procedure:

```
right click (on external monitor) --> Change Desktop Background --> click on a different background and then again on the previously selected one
```

My dual monitor setup is as follows:

- 13'' notebook panel, 1366x768
- 22'' external display, 1920x1080

According to AMDCCC my notebook panel is configured as the primary adapter (screen number 1).

This problem only affects the desktop itself. Wallpapers are rendered correctly on the login screen.

How can I prevent the system from messing up my wallpaper configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of research sessions I am none the wiser as to what causes this problem. But for now I have found a quick and dirty workaround that resets the wallpaper on each startup:

Create a folder under /usr/share/backgrounds:

```
sudo -s
cd /usr/share/backgrounds
mkdir Hotfix
```

Make two copies of the wallpaper you plan on using and move them to the newly created folder:

```
cd /usr/share/backgrounds/Hotfix
cp /path/to/image.jpg 1.jpg
cp /path/to/image.jpg 2.jpg
```

Create a script in your home directory:

```
cd ~
gedit .wallpaper.sh
```

Copy and paste the following commands and save it:

```
#!/bin/bash

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Hotfix/1.jpg
sleep 3
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Hotfix/2.jpg
```

Make your script executable:

```
chmod +x .wallpaper.sh
```

Add your script to the Startup applications:

[image]

[image]

[image]

That's it. You'll be able to enjoy your full-resolution wallpaper at last.